# Probability to win or lose tournament

Tags: probability

Task:

> Basketball team has probability $\frac{1}{3}$ to win match. In tournament they are playing three matches.
>
> 1. What is the probability that this team wins all three matches?
> 2. What is the probability that this team loses all three matches?
> 3. What probability of win should this team have to have probability of three wins more than 40%?

I solved it with binomial distribution. Part 1: $\frac{1}{27}$, Part 2: $\frac{8}{27}$ Part 3: I don't know.
Is my solution correct? What solution is  for part 3?

Comment: Didn't you just cube the probability of a win to get $\dfrac{1}{27}$? Then $$p^3 > .4$$ for some $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solutions for 1 and 2 are correct. Now, observe that your unknown variable here is the probability of winning a match. And you want that the probability of 3 wins is greater than 40%.

So as you probably did before, the probability of winning three matches is $p^3$ where $p$ is the probability of winning one match.

So you want that $p^3 > 0.4$ Since you want that the probability of winning three matches is $greater$ than $40 \% = 0.4$ Can you finish?

Comment: So, solution is $0.76$?

Comment: $p>(0.4)^{1/3} \approx 0.74$

Answer (score 1):

If the probability of winning is $p$, then the probability of winning $3$ times is $p^3$. Hence, for the probability of winning $3$ times to be more $40\%$ you need

$$ p^3 \geq 0.4 \Leftrightarrow p \geq 0.4^{\frac{1}{3}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your part 1 and 2.

**Hint** for Part 3 : let x be the probability of win. so $x^3$ > 40% = $\frac2 5$